# How to Set Height for the Drop Down of Select box

Tags: html, css

my selectbox is showing scroll when number of options are more than 20 i just want to show scrol in when options are more than 10

```
 <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: I've never tried, but try adding 'size' attribute to the <select>

Comment: i have already but not working

Comment: Yeah it changed it to multi select box, hahah

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Height of an HTML select box (dropdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570642/height-of-an-html-select-box-dropdown)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try adding this to the `<select>` element:

```
onfocus='this.size=10;' 
onblur='this.size=1;' 
onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();
```

like:

```
   <select onfocus='this.size=10;' onblur='this.size=1;' 
        onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
```

**[SAMPLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kEnC9/)**

Comment: @VinceCgto your way shows all the 10 options all at once.. the OP wants to show only one then show 10 on focus.

Comment: if i am select same value again..on change  event not work so select  size attribute no re sized. how to re size =1 when select a same value?.

Comment: This works really well. Had to add `style='height:auto'` to `select` to make the select box expand for some cases.

Answer (score 23):

Seriously guys, there is a size attribute for the `select` element:

```
<select size="10">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
</select>
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/UR46N/

Comment: This is how I interpreted it (and still do after re-reading your question). Oh well, glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Case of setting size (height/width) and fitting the selection list in the pop up then try the following in VFPage- Salesforce:

```
<apex:selectList onclick="this.size=5;" required="true" id="form-element-05" value="{!scheduleBatchWrapper.hour}" size="1" styleClass="slds-select selectObj  slds-m-left_medium slds-m-top_medium schTime" style="max-width:50%; margin-bottom:5% margin-top:5%,max-height:20%" >
                                                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!scheduleBatchWrapper.hoursList}"></apex:selectOptions>
                                                                        </apex:selectList>
```

// here onclick="this.size=5;" will set the size to 5 when you click on the selectList.
//it works fine for Chrome,Firefox,Edge.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As much as I see, none of the former answers explain the Options box.
As much as I know, we don't have accessibility to manipulate options in a select box.
We just can change the colors and background color at the same time, add a new font and that's all we could do.
If we add padding or margin to the Options, the drop-down list will be still the same as its initial condition.

The only way to do so is to design a select-box on your own( by using radio buttons, prevent their default style, and add a background color to it. )

Answer (score 0):

check this .i have implemented scroll to your select box. http://plnkr.co/edit/XiKZ4X2DGYTJDjJX2xvw?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
   onFocus={(e) => { e.target.size = 5;}}
   onBlur={(e) => { e.target.size = 1; }}
```

```js
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534440/how-to-set-height-for-the-drop-down-of-select-box#
```

```html
 <label htmlFor="University">
    <p>University</p>
      <select name="" id="University" onFocus={(e) => {e.target.size = 5;}}
        onBlur={(e) => {e.target.size = 1;}}>
         <option value="" selected>Select</option>
         <option value="LPU (Lovely Professional University)">LPU (Lovely Professional University)</option>
         <option value="GLA Mathura">GLA Mathura</option>
         <option value="LPU (Lovely Professional University)">LPU (Lovely Professional University)</option>
         <option value="GLA Mathura">GLA Mathura</option>
         <option value="LPU (Lovely Professional University)">LPU (Lovely Professional University)</option>
         <option value="GLA Mathura">GLA Mathura</option>
         <option value="LPU (Lovely Professional University)">LPU (Lovely Professional University)</option>
         <option value="GLA Mathura">GLA Mathura</option>
      </select>
    </label>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

option {
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation ?

Answer (score -1):

I am using Bootstrap and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19229738/1526703) helped me.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 280px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Would really appreciate any comment with a downvote so I could realise what was wrong

Answer (score -2):

Why dont you add CSS style to specify the width and height of the select.
Check the article--> http://cssdeck.com/labs/styling-select-box-with-css3

Answer (score -2):

use below css

```
select{ padding:5px;}
```