# Alter how many options in a select field are rendered in React

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, height

I have a select field with a bunch of options:

```
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>6</option>
   <option>7</option>
   <option>8</option>
   <option>9</option>
   <option>10</option>
</select>
```

I am using React, and because of a lack of height available on my page, I want to restrict my select field so that when a user clicks it, not all 10 options are seen, only 5.

I have looked at and tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534569/4637110) and using camelcase versions of the attributes mentioned (onBlur, onFocus) etc, but this is not effective in React, returning console errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **onFocus** and **onBlur** events to set your target size.

```
<select onFocus={(e) => e.target.size = 5} onBlur={(e) => e.target.size = 1}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/42933/)