# how to scroll years using pikaday?

Tags: javascript, css, date, pikaday

I am using pikaday.min.js and pikaday.min.css in my project. The problem is with the years. When I click the year, the options are the chosen year -/+ 10 years, but there is no scroll option when the grey box pops up.

For ex. if I want to select year 2002 in the example below, I must select years <2012 in order that 2002 shows up. I hope I am clear enough

[image]

```
@charset "UTF-8";/*!
 * Pikaday
 * Copyright © 2014 David Bushell | BSD & MIT license | https://dbushell.com/
 */.pika-single{z-index:9999;display:block;position:relative;color:#333;background:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc;border-bottom-color:#bbb;font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif}
    
    .pika-single:after,.pika-single:before{content:" ";display:table}
    .pika-single:after{clear:both}
    .pika-single.is-hidden{display:none}
    .pika-single.is-bound{position:absolute;box-shadow:0 5px 15px -5px rgba(0,0,0,.5)}
    .pika-lendar{float:left;width:240px;margin:8px}
    .pika-title{position:relative;text-align:center}
    .pika-label{display:inline-block;position:relative;z-index:9999;overflow:scroll;margin:0;padding:5px 3px;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;font-weight:700;background-color:#fff}
    .pika-title select{cursor:pointer;position:absolute;z-index:9998;margin:0;left:0;top:5px;opacity:0}
    .pika-next,.pika-prev{display:block;cursor:pointer;position:relative;outline:0;border:0;padding:0;width:20px;height:30px;text-indent:20px;white-space:nowrap;overflow:scroll;background-color:transparent;background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:75% 75%;opacity:.5}
    .pika-next:hover,.pika-prev:hover{opacity:1}.is-rtl 
    .pika-next,.pika-prev{float:left;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAYAAAAsEj5rAAAAUklEQVR42u3VMQoAIBADQf8Pgj+OD9hG2CtONJB2ymQkKe0HbwAP0xucDiQWARITIDEBEnMgMQ8S8+AqBIl6kKgHiXqQqAeJepBo/z38J/U0uAHlaBkBl9I4GwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)}
    .is-rtl .pika-prev,.pika-next{float:right;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAeCAYAAAAsEj5rAAAAU0lEQVR42u3VOwoAMAgE0dwfAnNjU26bYkBCFGwfiL9VVWoO+BJ4Gf3gtsEKKoFBNTCoCAYVwaAiGNQGMUHMkjGbgjk2mIONuXo0nC8XnCf1JXgArVIZAQh5TKYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=)}
    .pika-next.is-disabled,.pika-prev.is-disabled{cursor:default;opacity:.2}
    .pika-select{display:inline-block}
    .pika-table{width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border:0}
    .pika-table td,.pika-table th{width:14.285714285714286%;padding:0}
    .pika-table th{color:#999;font-size:12px;line-height:25px;font-weight:700;text-align:center}
    .pika-button{cursor:pointer;display:block;box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;outline:0;border:0;margin:0;width:100%;padding:5px;color:#666;font-size:12px;line-height:15px;text-align:right;background:#f5f5f5;height:initial}
    .pika-week{font-size:11px;color:#999}
    .is-today .pika-button{color:#3af;font-weight:700}
    .has-event .pika-button,.is-selected .pika-button{color:#fff;font-weight:700;background:#3af;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px #178fe5;border-radius:3px}
    .has-event .pika-button{background:#005da9;box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px #0076c9}
    .is-disabled .pika-button,.is-inrange .pika-button{background:#d5e9f7}
    .is-startrange .pika-button{color:#fff;background:#6cb31d;box-shadow:none;border-radius:3px}
    .is-endrange .pika-button{color:#fff;background:#3af;box-shadow:none;border-radius:3px}
    .is-disabled .pika-button{pointer-events:none;cursor:default;color:#999;opacity:.3}
    .is-outside-current-month .pika-button{color:#999;opacity:.3}
    .is-selection-disabled{pointer-events:none;cursor:default}
    .pika-button:hover,.pika-row.pick-whole-week:hover .pika-button{color:#fff;background:#ff8000;box-shadow:none;border-radius:3px}
    .pika-table abbr{border-bottom:none;cursor:help}
```

Comment: can you provide some code, this should be a CSS issue.

Comment: The size is depending on the platform/browser. So you're probably on MacOs, thats why it's not scrolling.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Set Height for the Drop Down of Select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534440/how-to-set-height-for-the-drop-down-of-select-box)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a CSS issue.
The Example on https://pikaday.com/ supports scrolling.

Try to make the element scrollable with e.g.:

```html
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;">
```

Comment: even in https://pikaday.com/ the year does scroll

Comment: yes, therefore reduce the height of the selection box

Comment: please check the code that I added in the question, where do you think I should change it @true_gler

Comment: thanks @true_gler :) problem was solved with adding yearRange in js