# How can I limit the options in an HTML <select> dropdown?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I want to limit my options in the select tag.

**For Example**

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    ......
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

I want to show only the first 5 options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Set Height for the Drop Down of Select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23534440/how-to-set-height-for-the-drop-down-of-select-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add this into your  tag:

```
<select onmousedown="if(this.options.length>5){this.size=5;}"> 
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```