# custom scroll-bar for select box

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to add the custom scrollbar for select box, I have tried with following code but I don't want to use the default scrollbar in the select box, I want to apply custom scrollbar and I also don't want to use size attribute on the select element.

```
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Please help how to add the custom scrollbar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have a scroll bar in drop down list HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892204/have-a-scroll-bar-in-drop-down-list-html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```css
  .wrapper{
    border: 1px dashed red;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 150px;
 }
 .wrapper .selection{
   width:150px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<select class="selection" size="15">
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to change the height of the select box, I want to change the default styling of the scroll bar. in your example default scrollbar is appearing.