# drop-down checkbox input in shiny

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny

Is it possible to have a dropdown list in Shiny where you can select multiple values? I know `selectInput` has the option to set `multiple = T` but I don't like it that all selected option are visible in the screen, especially since I have over 40. The same holds for `checkboxGroupInput()`, which I like more but still all selected values are shown. Isn't it just possible to get a drop-down like the one I copied from Excel below, rather than the examples of Shinys `selectInput` and `checkboxGroupInput()` thereafter?

[image: Excel] [image: shiny1] [image: shiny2] [image: shiny3]

Comment: It looks like you'll have to create your own custom shiny widget :)

Comment: Was hoping that there was an other solution given my lack of knowledge or CSS/HTML....

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**EDIT** : This function (and others) is available in package [`shinyWidgets`](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets)

---

Hi I wrote this `dropdownButton` function once, it create a bootstrap dropdown button (doc [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns)), the results looks like :

[image: dropdown button]

Here is the code :

```
# func --------------------------------------------------------------------

dropdownButton <- function(label = "", status = c("default", "primary", "success", "info", "warning", "danger"), ..., width = NULL) {

  status <- match.arg(status)
  # dropdown button content
  html_ul <- list(
    class = "dropdown-menu",
    style = if (!is.null(width)) 
      paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"),
    lapply(X = list(...), FUN = tags$li, style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;")
  )
  # dropdown button apparence
  html_button <- list(
    class = paste0("btn btn-", status," dropdown-toggle"),
    type = "button", 
    `data-toggle` = "dropdown"
  )
  html_button <- c(html_button, list(label))
  html_button <- c(html_button, list(tags$span(class = "caret")))
  # final result
  tags$div(
    class = "dropdown",
    do.call(tags$button, html_button),
    do.call(tags$ul, html_ul),
    tags$script(
      "$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
});")
  )
  }
```

And an example :

```
# app ---------------------------------------------------------------------

library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Example dropdown button"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      dropdownButton(
        label = "Check some boxes", status = "default", width = 80,
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check1", label = "Choose", choices = paste(1:26, ") Choice ", LETTERS))
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1")
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      dropdownButton(
        label = "Check some boxes", status = "default", width = 80,
        actionButton(inputId = "a2z", label = "Sort A to Z", icon = icon("sort-alpha-asc")),
        actionButton(inputId = "z2a", label = "Sort Z to A", icon = icon("sort-alpha-desc")),
        br(),
        actionButton(inputId = "all", label = "(Un)select all"),
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check2", label = "Choose", choices = paste(1:26, ") Choice ", LETTERS))
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res1 <- renderPrint({
    input$check1
  })

  # Sorting asc
  observeEvent(input$a2z, {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session = session, inputId = "check2", choices = paste(1:26, ") Choice ", LETTERS), selected = input$check2
    )
  })
  # Sorting desc
  observeEvent(input$z2a, {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session = session, inputId = "check2", choices = paste(26:1, ") Choice ", rev(LETTERS)), selected = input$check2
    )
  })
  output$res2 <- renderPrint({
    input$check2
  })
  # Select all / Unselect all
  observeEvent(input$all, {
    if (is.null(input$check2)) {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(
        session = session, inputId = "check2", selected = paste(1:26, ") Choice ", LETTERS)
      )
    } else {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(
        session = session, inputId = "check2", selected = ""
      )
    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In bonus I put the ascending/descending sorting thingy in the second dropdown buttons.

**EDIT Mar 22 '16**

To split yours checkboxes into multiple columns you can do the split yourself with `fluidRow` and `columns` and multiples checkboxes, you just have to bind the values server-side.
To implement scrolling put your checkboxes into a div with `style='overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px;'`.

Look at this example :

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Example dropdown button"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      dropdownButton(
        label = "Check some boxes", status = "default", width = 450,
        tags$label("Choose :"),
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 4,
            checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check1a", label = NULL, choices = paste0(1:10, ") ", LETTERS[1:10]))
          ),
          column(
            width = 4,
            checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check1b", label = NULL, choices = paste0(11:20, ") ", LETTERS[11:20]))
          ),
          column(
            width = 4,
            checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check1c", label = NULL, choices = paste0(21:26, ") ", LETTERS[21:26]))
          )
        )
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res1")
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      tags$style(".container { border:2px solid steelblue; width: 100%; height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll; }"),
      dropdownButton(
        label = "Check some boxes", status = "default", width = 120,
        tags$div(
          class = "container",
          checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check2", label = "Choose", choices = paste0(1:26, ") ", LETTERS))
        )
      ),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res2")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  valuesCheck1 <- reactiveValues(x = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$check1a, valuesCheck1$x <- unique(c(valuesCheck1$x, input$check1a)))
  observeEvent(input$check1b, valuesCheck1$x <- unique(c(valuesCheck1$x, input$check1b)))
  observeEvent(input$check1c, valuesCheck1$x <- unique(c(valuesCheck1$x, input$check1c)))

  output$res1 <- renderPrint({
    valuesCheck1$x
  })

  output$res2 <- renderPrint({
    input$check2
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Seems that the width argument is not working. If I change 40 to say, 80, nothing changes.

Comment: Solution: Simply add style=("width: 120px;"), to the to the html button appearance.

Comment: The width args works, try `width = "100%"` or "width = 400", it's just that 40 or 80 are too small, you cannot set a width lower than the width of the child element

Comment: Thanks, you're right. A (de)select option all would also be a nice feature but I read on the internet that this requires CSS.

Comment: It's also possible with an `actionButton`, I edited my answer, rerun the code and see the second dropdown button.

Comment: Thanks again @Victorp

Comment: Why not use `submitButton` ? `tags$submit` is ``NULL` for me, I'm not sure it's a valid HTML tag.

Comment: I just implemented it and therefore deleted my comment. However, the `submitButton` seems to impact the `De(select) all` as well...So everytime I select all, they are only selected if I hit submit. And also all other filters are not applied, only if I hist submit. I would like to have it in the dropdown as it only needs to affect the dropdown.

Comment: `submitButton` impact all the input. Look at http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html for more on buttons in shiny

Comment: Thanks, already implemented that but was hoping it would be possible to have it in the dropdown filter. Just as I was hoping to add a scroll-bar, but that is not straightforward to me to implement in shiny from this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227496/scrollable-menu-with-bootstrap-3-menu-expanding-its-container-when-it-should-n

Comment: This function doesn't seem to work with navbarMenu(). Has anyone encounter this?

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht Hi Tim, were you able to implement a scroll bar on this in the end?

Comment: @ishido Unfortunately not.. I'm currently using datatable's for filtering with y_scrolling enabled. But this is far from ideal.. Would love to have the scroll bar in.

Comment: @Victorp Dear Victor, this is a great solution to shiny, thank you. If the menu is very long, is there a way to split it into multiple columns or maybe implement a scroll bar? I'm having troubles understanding the code.

Comment: @ishido Have you found any way to split into columns already?

Comment: @John Hey, I didn't sorry. ended up fitting the dashboard to longer lists I think (was a while back)

Comment: The function pickerInput in the shinywidgets package is now another option which meets the orignal request, as an alternative to using dropdownButton.

Comment: why when I unselect a letter it keeps shown in the text output?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, lot of thanks for this *dropdownButton* function. It's very useful!

Secondly, i tried to use it into shiny dashboard sidebarmenu, but the default  characters' style is "color:white" (because of dark background). That takes me a couple of hour to understand that can be changed inside your function, more precisly in *html_ul* stuff. Here's the line of interest, with *color:black* :

```
lapply(X = list(...), FUN = tags$li, style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; color:black")
```

Quite simple... But when you don't know it (R is the only language I know)... So, I hope this will help any other css-ignorant (and/or HTML?) like me!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple questions in the comments related the the dropdownButton (worked great for me, thank you) about how to create a **scrolling bar** on the dropdown. Sorry I don't have reputation to reply in the comments directly.

Try tweaking the relevant ID in your styles.css, for whatever object you put in the dropdownButton. So for the example, the checkboxGroupInput ID needs to have:

```
#check1
{
   height: 200px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

**Edit:**

To call the styles.css in the ui.R:

```
navbarPage("Superzip", id="nav",

  tabPanel("Interactive map",
    div(class="outer",

      tags$head(
        # Include our custom CSS
        includeCSS("styles.css")
      ),

      leafletOutput("map", width="100%", height="100%"), 
      ...
```

And the styles.css, with the auto overflow for the inputID `ttype` and `chain`:

```
input[type="number"] {


max-width: 80%;
}

div.outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 41px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Customize fonts */
body, label, input, button, select { 
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
  font-weight: 200;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 { font-weight: 400; }

#controls {
  /* Appearance */
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  cursor: move;
  /* Fade out while not hovering */
  opacity: 0.65;
  zoom: 0.9;
  transition: opacity 500ms 1s;
}
#controls:hover {
  /* Fade in while hovering */
  opacity: 0.95;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

#data_inputs {
  /* Appearance */
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
  cursor: move;
  /* Fade out while not hovering */
  opacity: 0.65;
  zoom: 0.9;
  transition: opacity 500ms 1s;
}
#data_inputs:hover {
  /* Fade in while hovering */
  opacity: 0.95;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

/* Position and style citation */
#cite {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#cite {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#ttype
{
   height: 200px;
   overflow: auto;
}

#chain
{
   height: 200px;
   overflow: auto;
}



."form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container"
{
   height: 50px;
   overflow: auto;
}

/* If not using map tiles, show a white background */
.leaflet-container {
  background-color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm still very interested in the scrollbar function. But I don't entirely get your answer, you  mean that this simple solution includes a scroll bar?!

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht It did for me. I'm no expert in HTML and CSS but it seems that you can just tell it to automatically use a scroll bar when an element is larger than the chosen height.

`dropdownButton(
                      label = "Chains", status = "default",
                      actionButton(inputId = "all_chains", label = "(Un)select all"),
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "chain", label = "", choices = chains, selected = chains)
                    )`

and in the style: 

`#chain
{
   height: 200px;
   overflow: auto;
}
`

Comment: me neither... Where do you load the styles.css? Could you maybe add your full styles.css file and the place where you call it in your answer?

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht See above, basically an adaption of the code from [this Shiny example](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/063-superzip-example)

Answer (score -1):

For future visitors that might need similar solutions, a good option could be the [selectizeInput](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html) .

Pros:

1. You can set the list length
2. Is a dropdown function
3. User can select one or more choices by searching the list
   or by typing in the box.

For more information check the above link. Hope this will help.

Cheers!

[image]