# shiny js: change the label of a button based on the user choice from that button

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm a shiny js newbie and seem to be at a stalemate with this issue.

I want to create a dropdown button whose label changes with the user choice from that button.

The following is my minimum reproducible code. I grabbed a dropdown button function from this post: [drop-down checkbox input in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530142/drop-down-checkbox-input-in-shiny):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

dropdownButton <- function(label = "", status = c("default", "primary", "success", "info", "warning", "danger"), ..., width = NULL) {
    status <- match.arg(status)
    # dropdown button content
    html_ul <- list(
        class = "dropdown-menu",
        style = if (is.null(width)) 
            paste0("width: 375px; overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 300px"), # width: validateCssUnit(width)
        lapply(X = list(...), FUN = tags$li, style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;")
    )
    # dropdown button apparence
    html_button <- list(
        class = paste0("btn btn-", status," dropdown-toggle"),
        type = "button", 
        `data-toggle` = "dropdown"
    )
    html_button <- c(html_button, list(label))
    html_button <- c(html_button, list(tags$span(class = "caret")))

    # final result
    tags$div(
        class = "dropdown",
        do.call(tags$button, html_button),
        do.call(tags$ul, html_ul),
        tags$script(
            "$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            });")
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("button")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$button <- renderUI({
    list(
      useShinyjs(),
      dropdownButton(label = "Cut Table By:", status = "default",
        radioButtons("letters", 
          NULL, 
          choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
          selected = "B")
      )
    )
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'd like the default label to the button to be "Cut Table by" (or it could even be the choice "B") but then when the user chooses another choice, change to that letter.

I think the part that confuses me the most is the radio button function imbedded in the drop down function, and that I somehow need to make an event with an input to the imbedded function that affects an input to the imbedding function. But perhaps the situation is simpler than it seems to me.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `dropdownButton` oppose to the `selectInput` ?

Comment: Yes, in some parts of my code, instead of radio button, I have a multiple choice check box imbedded in dropdownButton because I wanted a multiple choice dropdown button.

Answer (score 2):

You can add any element as `label` in your `button` tag. So the easiest way would be to make the label a reactive `textOutput` which then can react to the chosen `radioButton`. This way, you don't even have to change your `dropdownButton` function. The additions I made are pretty straightforward. Only mind that the `textOutput` must have `inline = TRUE` in order to not have an ugly break before the caret.

I modified your given code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

dropdownButton <- function(label = "", status = c("default", "primary", "success", "info", "warning", "danger"), ..., width = NULL) {
    status <- match.arg(status)
    # dropdown button content
    html_ul <- list(
        class = "dropdown-menu",
        style = if (is.null(width)) 
            paste0("width: 375px; overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 300px"), # width: validateCssUnit(width)
        lapply(X = list(...), FUN = tags$li, style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;")
    )
    # dropdown button apparence
    html_button <- list(
        class = paste0("btn btn-", status," dropdown-toggle"),
        type = "button", 
        `data-toggle` = "dropdown"
    )
    html_button <- c(html_button, list(label))
    html_button <- c(html_button, list(tags$span(class = "caret")))

    # final result
    tags$div(
        class = "dropdown",
        do.call(tags$button, html_button),
        do.call(tags$ul, html_ul),
        tags$script(
            "$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            });")
    )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("button")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$button <- renderUI({
    list(
      useShinyjs(),
      dropdownButton(label = textOutput("labels", inline = TRUE), status = "default",
        radioButtons("letters", 
          NULL, 
          choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
          selected = "B")
      )
    )
  }) 

  output$labels <- renderText(paste("Cut Table By:", input$letters))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: of course! thank you for your straightforward and simple suggestion. didn't have to use shiny js or modify anything.