# Error in multiple selectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, shiny

This app is meant to create a subset of a larger dataset based on the 2 inputs selection in Shiny app. I have used a dropdownbutton function I found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530142/drop-down-checkbox-input-in-shiny).

```
# func --------------------------------------------------------------------

dropdownButton <- function(label = "", status = c("default", "primary", "success", "info", "warning", "danger"), ..., width = NULL) {

  status <- match.arg(status)
  # dropdown button content
  html_ul <- list(
    class = "dropdown-menu",
    style = if (!is.null(width)) 
      paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"),
    lapply(X = list(...), FUN = tags$li, style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;")
  )
  # dropdown button apparence
  html_button <- list(
    class = paste0("btn btn-", status," dropdown-toggle"),
    type = "button", 
    `data-toggle` = "dropdown"
  )
  html_button <- c(html_button, list(label))
  html_button <- c(html_button, list(tags$span(class = "caret")))
  # final result
  tags$div(
    class = "dropdown",
    do.call(tags$button, html_button),
    do.call(tags$ul, html_ul),
    tags$script(
      "$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
});")
  )
  }
```

My app is meant to create a subset of a larger dataset based on the 2 inputs selection in Shiny app. For both dropdown menu, I want multiple select option similar to `multiple=TRUE` in `selectInput`. Although `dropdownbutton` menu allows me to select multiple options, it randomly omits data in output that should be included. I get the correct subset when I use `selectInput`. Any solutions?

Second, my `selectAll` button doesn't work.

The problem is that when I select

```
ou1 <- levels(df$OperatingUnit)
ou <- setNames(as.list(ou1),ou1)
indi1 <- levels(df$indicator)
indi <- setNames(as.list(indi1),indi1)

ui->...
inputPanel(
  dropdownButton(
  label = "Select OU", status = "default", width = 120, 
  actionButton(inputId = "all", label = "Select all"),
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check1", label = "Choose", choices = paste(ou))
),
dropdownButton(
  label = "Select Indicators", status = "default", width = 150, 
  checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check2", label = "Choose", choices = paste(indi))
),

tableOutput("tab1")

))
```

Server -->

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

dataset - changes based on menu selections
 df1 <- reactive({
  df[df$OperatingUnit==input$check1 & df$indicator==input$check2,]
})

output$tab1<- renderTable({
 head(df1(), n = 10)
})

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
 filename = function() { 
  paste("PSNU_IM", '.csv', sep='') 
},
content = function(file) {
  write.csv(df1(), file)
}
 )

# Select all / Unselect all
observeEvent(input$all, {
if (is.null(input$check1)) {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(
    session = session, inputId = "check1", selected = paste(ou)
  )
} else {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(
    session = session, inputId = "check1", selected = ""
    )
   }
  })
 })
)`
```

Subset of my data:

```
structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "Africa", class = "factor"), OperatingUnit = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Angola", "Botswana", 
"Cameroon"), class = "factor"), SNU1Uid = structure(c(5L, 5L, 
9L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 
4L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 2L), .Label = c("", "BTRiZA58YEx", "HxXMyMSODnm", 
"IaFLxtEwIwk", "Jm3YTCERxvX", "MERiZA58YEx", "MTRiZA58YEx", "MTRiZA68YEx", 
"MTRiZG58YEx"), class = "factor"), PSNUuid = structure(c(29L, 
11L, 23L, 23L, 10L, 29L, 1L, 13L, 18L, 30L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 15L, 
19L, 33L, 16L, 27L, 31L, 21L, 3L, 20L, 25L, 14L, 32L, 7L, 28L, 
22L, 22L, 24L, 12L, 16L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 17L, 26L), .Label = c("", 
"a2nQs7VmYiD", "AbJXFBhkc4U", "AFX0cjkDX6A", "AFX0djkDX6A", "AFX0djkFX6A", 
"AW764lDxjdr", "clasYX5teTV", "fHkrk3yL1uU", "gOaZeiwAoCD", "GP5qeoiXMtA", 
"hvNtuMClAXW", "hz2Tdvrxqbp", "JIcgSOsSpSV", "js5vRAkkqxB", "k7lIVnxWbm7", 
"KFX0djkDX6A", "MIvAFWhI9Yc", "Ns6ZJi0iwJj", "oAgxCCStCQe", "PJKaNADvNfi", 
"r5xWCJ4ZqYQ", "rjDWLPMhaY0", "VaHOXJU4rir", "vewKgey8sOW", "VFX0djkDX6A", 
"Vq1CnJNw46x", "vqaBeYFtUn0", "VZPPWeDuJqU", "YuCzvkHV2X5", "YXiMSh7CqES", 
"zU7eKPwFr69", "ZxJNWnk4hYW"), class = "factor"), indicator = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("CARE_CURR", "GEND_GBV", 
"GEND_NORM", "HRH_PRE", "TX_CURR", "TX_NEW"), class = "factor"), 
    numeratorDenom = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "N", class = "factor"), indicatorType = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("DSD", 
    "TA"), class = "factor"), disaggregate = structure(c(4L, 
    1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 
    6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Age/Sex", 
    "Age/Sex Aggregated", "Age/Sex, Aggregated", "Aggregated Age/Sex", 
    "Grad Cadre", "Total Numerator"), class = "factor"), categoryOptionComboName = structure(c(8L, 
    7L, 16L, 13L, 13L, 23L, 19L, 14L, 9L, 3L, 13L, 16L, 21L, 
    2L, 17L, 13L, 13L, 2L, 11L, 13L, 18L, 1L, 14L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 
    23L, 12L, 20L, 6L, 22L, 15L, 7L, 12L, 16L, 5L, 2L, 12L, 16L, 
    5L, 2L), .Label = c("<1, Female", "<1, Male", "<10, Female", 
    "<15, Male", "1-4, Male", "10-14, Male", "15-19, Female", 
    "15+, Female", "15+, Male", "20+, Female", "20+, Male", "5-14, Male", 
    "default", "Female, 15-19", "Female, 20-24", "Female, 25-49", 
    "Female, 5-9", "Female, 50+", "Lab Professionals", "Male, <1", 
    "Male, 1-4", "Male, 20-24", "Male, 50+"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = structure(c(10L, 9L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 
    3L, 1L, 13L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 1L, 14L, 2L, 9L, 
    4L, 2L, 12L, 14L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 5L, 
    2L, 7L, 13L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("  ", "  <01", "  <10", 
    "  <15", "  01-04", "  05-09", "  05-14", "  10-14", "  15-19", 
    "  15+", "  20-24", "  20+", "  25-49", "  50+"), class = "factor"), 
    Sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("", "Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
    FY2016Q4 = c(60L, 42L, 144L, 606L, 977L, 509L, 475L, 827L, 
    455L, 966L, 432L, 372L, 333L, 0L, 583L, 339L, 423L, 107L, 
    341L, 45L, 818L, 299L, 679L, 261L, 964L, 338L, 470L, 879L, 
    421L, 351L, 490L, 464L, 416L, 844L, 752L, 708L, 506L, 889L, 
    230L, 586L, 576L), FY2016APR = c(4L, 471L, 106L, 876L, 873L, 
    490L, 65L, 360L, 232L, 673L, 646L, 548L, 495L, 846L, 215L, 
    11L, 405L, 953L, 411L, 610L, 907L, 755L, 580L, 967L, 594L, 
    213L, 227L, 54L, 25L, 930L, 266L, 512L, 277L, 150L, 454L, 
    478L, 720L, 666L, 249L, 886L, 781L), FY2017_TARGETS = c(464L, 
    853L, 907L, 598L, 685L, 791L, 232L, 981L, 217L, 705L, 920L, 
    890L, 144L, 545L, 159L, 615L, 72L, 570L, 325L, 138L, 919L, 
    743L, 316L, 673L, 867L, 488L, 652L, 683L, 805L, 616L, 701L, 
    911L, 985L, 595L, 576L, 132L, 396L, 856L, 721L, 353L, 105L
    )), .Names = c("Region", "OperatingUnit", "SNU1Uid", "PSNUuid", 
"indicator", "numeratorDenom", "indicatorType", "disaggregate", 
"categoryOptionComboName", "Age", "Sex", "FY2016Q4", "FY2016APR", 
"FY2017_TARGETS"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -41L
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi when you filter your `data.frame` use `%in%` instead of `==` because the two vectors you compare don't have the same length, e.g. :

```
df1 <- reactive({
  df[df$OperatingUnit %in% input$check1 & df$indicator %in% input$check2, ]
})
```

For the second "select all" button you have to put an `observeEvent` in your server if you want that something happen if you click on it :

```
observeEvent(input$all1, {
  if (is.null(input$check2)) {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session = session, inputId = "check2", selected = paste(indi)
    )
  } else {
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(
      session = session, inputId = "check2", selected = ""
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! `%in%` solved the first problem.

For the second, I have tried to do selectAll only for ou, the server code has the observe event bit. But, when I click the selectAll button, the app closes and I get this error:

`Warning: Error in paste: object 'ou' not found`

P.S. have corrected my code

Comment: Load your data and create `ou` in `global.R` not `ui.R`