# dropdownButton alignment within dashboardSidebar

Tags: r, user-interface, button, drop-down-menu, shiny

I'm using the dropdownButton function from this link [drop-down checkbox input in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530142/drop-down-checkbox-input-in-shiny) that is in shinyWidgets, with a slight modification so that the text is black.

I want the dropdownButton to look like the selectInput drop down I have above it as much as possible. I got them to line up in the sidebar with column(1,) function, but I also want the width of the dropdownButton to be the same width as the selectInput.

I also got the width of the dropdown **choices** to be the same width of the selectInput above it with width=200, but I want the dropdown **button** to also be the same size.

Can someone help me modify  the dropDownButton function or my UI so that this is the case?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


dropdownButton2 <- function(label = "", status = c("default", "primary", "success", "info", "warning", "danger"), ..., width = NULL) {

  status <- match.arg(status)
  # dropdown button content
  html_ul <- list(
    class = "dropdown-menu",
    style = if (!is.null(width)) 
      paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"),
    lapply(X = list(...), FUN = tags$li, style = "margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;color:black")
  )
  # dropdown button apparence
  html_button <- list(
    class = paste0("btn btn-", status," dropdown-toggle"),
    type = "button", 
`    data-toggle` = "dropdown"
  )
  html_button <- c(html_button, list(label))
  html_button <- c(html_button, list(tags$span(class = "caret")))
  # final result
  tags$div(
    class = "dropdown",
    do.call(tags$button, html_button),
    do.call(tags$ul, html_ul),
    tags$script(
  "$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});")
  )
  }

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 325,
               selectInput('month',label='Filter 1:',choices= month.name,multiple = FALSE,selected = "March"),
               br(),
               column(1,
               h5(strong(("Filter 2:"))),
               dropdownButton2(
                 label = "Filter 2:", status = "default", width = 200,#circle = FALSE,
                 checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check1", label = "Choose", choices = c("A","B","C"))
               )
                 )),
  dashboardBody()         
  )

server <- function(input, output){
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by adding the `css` tag `tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".btn-default{width: 275px;}")` in your `ui` code as below:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 325,
                     selectInput('month',label='Filter 1:',choices= month.name,multiple = FALSE,selected = "March"),
                     br(),
                     column(1,
                            h5(strong(("Filter 2:"))),
                            tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".btn-default{width: 275px;}"),
                            dropdownButton2(
                              label = "Filter 2:", status = "default", width = 200,#circle = FALSE,
                              checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check1", label = "Choose", choices = c("A","B","C"))
                            )
                     )),
    dashboardBody()         
  )
```

On adding the tag you get something like this:

[image]

**[EDIT]:**
I later realized that the caret was not right aligned as in the case of `selectInput` hence to align that I further added couple of css tags as follows:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(width = 325,
                     selectInput('month',label='Filter 1:',choices= month.name,multiple = FALSE,selected = "March"),
                     br(),
                     column(1,
                            h5(strong(("Filter 2:"))),

                            tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".btn-default{width: 275px;}"),
                            tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".btn .caret{position: relative;}"),
                            tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".caret{top: 45%; right:-35%}"),
                            dropdownButton2(
                              label = "Filter 2:", status = "default", width = 200,#circle = FALSE,
                              checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "check1", label = "Choose", choices = c("A","B","C"))
                            )
                     )),
    dashboardBody()         
  )
```

The additional tags resulted the caret to be aligned as follows:
[image]

Comment: Perfect! This did exactly what I want.

Comment: So one issue I'm coming accross now is that I'd rather the size of the drop down button be reactive, since the selectInput button is goes between two different sizes based on the size of the window. I tried tags$style(type = 'text/css', ".btn-default{width: 100%;}"), but at certain window sizes the button gets small and the next sidebar item overlaps it... would you know how to fix this?