# R ShinyWidgets Embedded dropdownButton

Tags: r, shiny

The `dropdownButton` function from `shinyWidgets` is great because I can use it to easily create Check / Uncheck all options in a `checkboxGroupInput` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530142/drop-down-checkbox-input-in-shiny).

However, let's say I want to put two (or more) of these `dropdownButton`s together in another `dropdownButton`. I can't seem to make this work. Here is my attempt. (I am building the `ui` items within the `server.R` script because in my actual project, I need them to work that way.)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Dropsdowns in your Dropdowns"),
    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
        uiOutput("io_c1"),
        uiOutput("io_c2"),
        uiOutput("io_combine")
    ),
    mainPanel())
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    ## drop down 1 items ##
    # drop down 1 choices
    c1 <- checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId = "check1",
        label = "pick carb",
        choices = unique(mtcars$carb),
        selected = unique(mtcars$carb)
    )

    # select all / none drop down 1
    sa1 <- actionButton(inputId = "c1_check_all",
                        label = "(un)select all")

    # set up observe on check box 1
    observeEvent(input$c1_check_all, {
        if (is.null(input$check1)) {
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(
                session = session,
                inputId = "check1",
                selected = unique(mtcars$carb)
            )
        } else {
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(
                session = session,
                inputId = "check1",
                selected = ""
            )
        }
    })

    # put all / none button and check box 1 into a dropdownbutton
    output$io_c1 <- renderUI({
        dropdownButton(sa1,
                       c1,
                       circle = FALSE,
                       label = "Carbs",
                       status = "default")
    })

    ## drop down 2 items ##
    # drop down 2 choices
    c2 <- checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId = "check2",
        label = "pick gear",
        choices = unique(mtcars$gear),
        selected = unique(mtcars$gear)
    )

    # select all / none drop down 2
    sa2 <- actionButton(inputId = "c2_check_all",
                        label = "(un)select all")

    # set up observe on check box 2
    observeEvent(input$c2_check_all, {
        if (is.null(input$check2)) {
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(
                session = session,
                inputId = "check2",
                selected = unique(mtcars$gear)
            )
        } else {
            updateCheckboxGroupInput(
                session = session,
                inputId = "check2",
                selected = ""
            )
        }
    })

    # put all / none button and check box 2 into a dropdownbutton
    output$io_c2 <- renderUI({
        dropdownButton(sa2,
                       c2,
                       circle = FALSE,
                       label = "Gears",
                       status = "default")
    })

    ## now try to make this all one thing ##
    d1 <-  dropdownButton(sa1,
                          c1,
                          circle = FALSE,
                          label = "Carbs",
                          status = "default")

    d2 <- dropdownButton(sa2,
                         c2,
                         circle = FALSE,
                         label = "Gears",
                         status = "default")

    output$io_combine <-
        renderUI(dropdownButton(
            d1,
            d2,
            circle = FALSE,
            label = "Drop Downs Here",
            status = "default"
        ))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So I got this working with each of the individual `dropdownButton`s , but when I try to put the results all together into one in that third part of the code, it does not work. The `dropdownButton` is created and the two separate `dropdownButton`s are in there, but they don't respond at all. Any ideas what I might be missing?