# Double checkbox input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Similar to [drop-down checkbox input in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530142/drop-down-checkbox-input-in-shiny) I was looking for the option to create a `checkboxInput()` with two clickable columns such that that if the user needs to group by "X" then "X" is clicked if it wasn't marked as selected. Example:

[image]

While I could do this:

```
checkboxInput("select", "Selected variables", c("A", "B", "C"))

checkboxInput("group", "Grouping variables", c("A", "B", "C"))
```

I would prefer this:

```
checkboxInputDouble("vars", "Variables", 
 select = c("A", "B", "C"), 
 group = c("A", "B", "C"), 
 select_2 = c("A", "B")
 group_2 = c("B")
)
```

Comment: A simpler idea might be to use `actionButton` to pop up a `modalDialog` and have your checkbox UI there. Just a thought...

Comment: Not completely the layout you're searching for, but you might have a look at the package shinyWidgets and its button-checkboxes. You may use two of these checkboxes consecutively. It may not look the way you wished, but it's at least a better solution than using two normal checkbox-inputs this way. See: https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets.

Comment: I would also recommend `shinyWidgets` or you create a [custom input binding](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-custom-input.html) for it.